# C# Decrypt AES CBC pkcs1 padding, there is System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode.PKCS7 but does not have PKCS1

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, pkcs#7, pkcs

I need to decrypt a cipher that was encrypted with AES CBC 128 with PKCS1 padding.
But, C# AesCryptoServiceProvider and System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode does not have PKCS1.

What should I do?
Do I have to use some other AES package? or, implement my own...

Please help...

Comment: I'm for sure I have seen this questions some hours ago??? There is not PKCS1 padding with AES algorithm, just PKCS5 (naming in Java) and PKCS7 (naming in C#).

Comment: Thanks that makes sense but then the other team I am working with they are sure that it is AES with PKCS1... And, I also tried to use PKCS7 padding mode but the output looks like some corrupted data. The other team dev wrote a python script and it decrypted ok... how can I tell if what the padding was used or to verify... I literally tried all the padding mode in System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode

Comment: Use PKCS7 and it says 'Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.'

Comment: I figured out the problem is the Key byte array was set to the base64 version of the string in byte array... stupid mistake. Thank you Michael

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed.
Changed from

```
AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
aes.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
```

to

```
AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
aes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
```

Answer (score 1):

actually had the same problem but your suggestion will cause compile error, this worked for me.

```
AesCryptoServiceProvider aesCipher = new AesCryptoServiceProvider()
string keyBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(secretKey.Key); // secretKey is previusly generated AES Key using  Aes aes = Aes.Create(); and aes.GenerateKey();
byte[] textBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(keyBase64);
aesCipher.Key = textBytes;
aesCipher.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
aesCipher.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
```

and finally:

```
// Encrypt
byte[] payloadBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text); // payload for encryption
var payloadEncryptedBytes = aesCipher.CreateEncryptor()
            .TransformFinalBlock(payloadBytes, 0, payloadBytes.Length);

// Encode
return Convert.ToBase64String(payloadEncryptedBytes);
```